# Did God create man to replace the fallen Angels?

Tags: nature-of-god, creation, angels, nature-of-man

As near as I can determine from Scripture; Creation and ejection of the rebellious angels, both happened at about the same period.

That led me to begin to wonder, since it seems logical to me that God created the Angels for a specific duty.

It also seemed logical that the rebellious Angels being ejected would leave some functions undone, and if my concepts gained from Revelation are true that would probably be in the area of worship.

Of course God could simply create more Angels, but in creating man he could have man make the choice of whether to worship him or Satan before placing them in Heaven as is the procedure for entering the Ultimate Heaven.

Comment: What kind of answers are you looking for, protestant, catholic, orthodox, other?  Nobody wants to answer a question using Tradition that contradicts the question.

Comment: @ Peter Turner If there are any traditions concerning this question either pro or con I would like to have them. Thank you Cecil

Comment: Where in scripture do you find a timeline? According to the Book of Enoch the fallen angels came down on Mount Hermon and started teaching humanity. So the humans were already well established. Or are you talking about the fallen angels that destroyed the earth so that it was without form and void. Or the angels that destroyed the earth after Adam so that God had to make a new earth and a new Adam. I find the Mount Hermon angels the best developed and therefore the most interesting. They had cool names.

Comment: I draw my timeline from the following scriptures;

Comment: Isa_14:12  How art thou fallen from heaven, O Lucifer, son of the morning! how art thou cut down to the ground, which didst weaken the nations! 
Luk_10:18  And he said unto them, I beheld Satan as lightning fall from heaven. 
If Satan was cast to the ground, it must be between Genesis 1:1 and Genesis 3:1

Comment: There is a theory like that for that period. Not quite Biblical. Forgotten what it was all about. Angel wars etc. Maybe somebody else will know. Would be interesting.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it doesn't inquire into any **particular** tradition's official, historical, or widely accepts beliefs.

Comment: See [my answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/53410/1787) to [this related question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/53399/1787).

Comment: @Geremia Whether or not Humans are to replace fallen Angels is moot as the Souls of man and Angels are both Spirits and engage in honoring and singing praises to God. The only difference between the Angels and Souls is in the fact that Angels were created then chose whether or not to obey God, while mankind  was the opposite. Adam made the initial choice ,but God in  his wisdom provided Adam's posterity with the opportunity to make that decision for themselves by the blood of Jesus the Christ.

Answer (score 1):

The following is a Bible based answer. This is what Jehovah's Witnesses believe.

Creation and the eviction of rebellious angels from heaven did not occur at the same time. The angels were in existence before the creation of the earth. ([Job 38:4, 7](http://www.jw.org/en/publications/bible/nwt/books/job/38/#v18038004)) The earth has been given to mankind as a home, not a testing ground. ([Psalm 115:16](http://www.jw.org/en/publications/bible/nwt/books/psalms/115/#v19115016), [Psalm 37:29](http://www.jw.org/en/publications/bible/nwt/books/psalms/37/#v19037029))

The eviction of rebellious angels from heaven did not happen until Jesus was appointed as the king of God's kingdom. Under inspiration, David helps us to see that at some point, the Messiah would receive a certain amount of authority, but that after this he would still have to wait for a period of time before given authorization to act against his enemies:

> Psalm 110:1
>
> Jehovah declared to my Lord:
>
> “Sit at my right hand
>
> Until I place your enemies as a stool for your feet.”

In Acts, the Bible helps us to see that this refers to Jesus sitting at God's right hand after being resurrected back to heavenly life, and that even after that, there was still a waiting period before he would act against his enemies:

> Acts 2:32-35
>
> God resurrected this Jesus, and of this we are all witnesses.
> Therefore, because he was exalted to the right hand of God and
> received the promised holy spirit from the Father, he has poured out
> what you see and hear. For David did not ascend to the heavens, but he
> himself says, 'Jehovah said to my Lord: "Sit at my right hand until I
> place your enemies as a stool for your feet."'

[Bible prophecy and world events](http://www.jw.org/en/publications/books/bible-teach/1914-a-significant-year-in-bible-prophecy/) point toward the year 1914 as the year when Jesus was anointed to king of God's kingdom and he acted to evict Satan and his angels out of heaven, with Satan thereafter being confined to the earth. ([Revelation 12:7-12](http://www.jw.org/en/publications/bible/nwt/books/revelation/12/#v66012007)) The idea that this did not occur until the start of the "last days" is supported in Revelation 12:17 when it brings out that once the Devil is confined to the earth he knows he only "has a short period of time" remaining. ([2 Timothy 3:1-5](http://www.jw.org/en/publications/bible/nwt/books/2-timothy/3/#v55003001)) That means that we can rejoice because the time of living under Satan's "system of things" is nearing its end. ([2 Corinthians 4:4](http://www.jw.org/en/publications/bible/nwt/books/2-corinthians/4/#v47004004)) After that mankind can fully enjoy the earth as their home with God's physical and spiritual protection and blessing! ([Revelation 21:3, 4](http://www.jw.org/en/publications/bible/nwt/books/revelation/21/#v66021003); [1 Corinthians 15:26](http://www.jw.org/en/publications/bible/nwt/books/1-corinthians/15/#v46015026))

For more information look at this related question in the "Good News From God!" brochure: [What is God's Purpose for the Earth?](http://www.jw.org/en/publications/books/good-news-from-god/why-did-god-create-the-earth/)

Comment: Do you still check in here from time to time?

Comment: If the Angels were not evicted from Heaven until Jesus died on the Cross how do you account for his saying: >(Luke 10:18 KJV)  And he said unto them, I beheld Satan as lightning fall from heaven.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct.

Luke 20:34-36

And Jesus answering said unto them, The children of this world marry, and are given in marriage: But they which shall be accounted worthy to obtain that world, and the resurrection from the dead, neither marry, nor are given in marriage: Neither can they die any more: for they are equal unto the angels; and are the children of God, being the children of the resurrection.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  This next has nothing to do with the quality of your answer, it's just standard to help new visitors avoid misunderstanding the site (as I did at first.)  As a new visitor, I'd recommend checking out the following two posts, which are meant to help newcomers "learn the ropes": [the help page](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) and [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites)

Comment: How does that passage support the idea that God created humans to replace fallen angels?