# Does God intend to replace the fallen angels with humans?

Tags: catholicism, angels, humanity

[Fr. Chad Ripperger](http://www.sensustraditionis.org/), [FSSP](http://fssp.org/), says (@[3:19ff. of this video](https://youtu.be/HROH926Ln-A?t=3m19s)) that humans were created to replace the fallen angels. **Is this an official teaching of Catholic Church?**

[Bl. Anne Catherine Emmerich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anne_Catherine_Emmerich) also mentions this in her writings; however, they are private revelations.

My question here is related to [this question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/19821/1787), but from a Catholic perspective.

Answer (score 2):

[At 3:19ff. of the video you linked](https://youtu.be/HROH926Ln-A?t=3m19s), it sounds like Fr. Ripperger is speaking of what St. Thomas Aquinas discusses in his [*Summa Theologica* I q. 108 a. 8](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/FP/FP108.html#FPQ108A8THEP1), "Whether men are taken up into the angelic orders?" Here's part of that article:

> ***On the contrary,*** The Lord says of the saints that, "they will be as the angels of God" ([Mt. 22:30](http://drbo.org/x/d?b=drb&bk=47&ch=22&l=30#x)).
>
> ***I answer that***, As above explained ([a. 4](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/FP/FP108.html#FPQ108A4THEP1) & [7](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/FP/FP108.html#FPQ108A7THEP1)), the orders of the angels are distinguished according to the conditions of nature and according to the gifts of grace. Considered only as regards the grade of nature, men can in no way be assumed into the angelic orders; for the natural distinction will always remain. In view of this distinction, some asserted that men can in no way be transferred to an equality with the angels; but this is erroneous, contradicting as it does the promise of Christ saying that the children of the resurrection will be equal to the angels in heaven ([Lk. 20:36](http://drbo.org/x/d?b=drb&bk=49&ch=20&l=36#x)). For whatever belongs to nature is the material part of an order; whilst that which perfects is from grace which depends on the liberality of God, and not on the order of nature. Therefore by the gift of grace men can merit glory in such a degree as to be equal to the angels, in each of the angelic grades; and this implies that men are taken up into the orders of the angels. Some, however, say that not all who are saved are assumed into the angelic orders, but only virgins or the perfect; and that the other will constitute their own order, as it were, corresponding to the whole society of the angels. But this is against what Augustine says ([*De Civ. Dei* xii](http://www.newadvent.org/fathers/120112.htm), 9), that "there will not be two societies of men and angels, but only one; because the beatitude of all is to cleave to God alone."

Comment: I need the quote from the catechism where it says: The fallen angels are replaced by humans... St. Thomas A. writes: "Some, however, say" which means he just collects opinions...

Comment: @Grasper «_Thomas A. writes: "Some, however, say" which means he just collects opinions..._» An opinion which he refutes with the argument from St. Augustine. Also, everything in catechisms isn't necessarily infallible.

Comment: well, in that case, I doubt everything Thomas said is infallible. I read some of his writings and they sound really weird.

Comment: @Grasper See this: [_The Authority of St. Thomas Aquinas_](https://isidore.co/calibre/browse/book/3481) by Jacobus M. Ramírez, O.P.